# Zend Action Helper Not Loaded *Sometimes*

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a zend action helper which sporadically doesn't load.  I get the exception:

```
Action helper by name EditAction not found
```

Any ideas why sometimes it finds it, and sometimes it doesn't?

I changed the exception to list the contents of the action helper directory, and the file is there.  I also made it print out the contents of the helper...that's fine also.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to post some code to get some help. Can you post the class and an example of how you are trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are not registring your EditAction helper witch Zend Controller Action helper broker before using it . If your EditAction is located at  library/My/EditAction.php and the class is called My_EditAction then do this in bootstrap

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new My_EditAction());
```

Comment: I'm using ::addPath() instead...is that not enough?

Answer (score 0):

::addPath() should work well as well if you have the path setup correctly. I would still recommend using ::addHelper rather than addPath() if you have just one Action Helper . And if you have multiple Action helpers in the path you can use addPrefix() in the bootstrap instead of ::addHelper()

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('My_Action_Helpers');
```

To determine if a helper exists in the helper broker, use hasHelper($name), where $name is the short name of the helper (minus the prefix):

```
// Check if 'redirector' helper is registered with the broker:
    if (Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::hasHelper('redirector')) {
        echo 'Redirector helper registered';
    }
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html